# How to programatically set the category for a new Woocommerce Product Creation?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

The solution presented here allows me to easily create "Categories" for a wordpress post:

```
//Check if category already exists
$cat_ID = get_cat_ID( $category );

//If it doesn't exist create new category
if($cat_ID == 0) {
        $cat_name = array('cat_name' => $category);
    wp_insert_category($cat_name);
}

//Get ID of category again incase a new one has been created
$new_cat_ID = get_cat_ID($category);

// Create post object
$new_post = array(
    'post_title' => $headline,
    'post_content' => $body,
    'post_excerpt' => $excerpt,
    'post_date' => $date,
    'post_date_gmt' => $date,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_author' => 1,
    'post_category' => array($new_cat_ID)
);

// Insert the post into the database
wp_insert_post( $new_post );
```

However, Woocommerce doesn't recognise these categories. Woocommerce categories are stored somewhere else. How can I programmatically create the categories for woocommerce and what is the correct way to assign it to a new post?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Woocommerce categories are terms in the product_cat taxonomy. So, to create a category, you can use [`wp_insert_term`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_term/):

```
wp_insert_term(
  'New Category', // the term 
  'product_cat', // the taxonomy
  array(
    'description'=> 'Category description',
    'slug' => 'new-category'
  )
);
```

This returns the `term_id` and `term_taxonomy_id`, like this: `array('term_id'=>12,'term_taxonomy_id'=>34))`

Then, associating a new product with the category is simply associating the category `term_id` with the product post (products are posts in Woocommerce). First, create the product/post and then use [`wp_set_object_terms`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_set_object_terms/):

```
wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $term_id, 'product_cat' );
```

Btw, woocommerce offers functions for these too which might be easier to use but I have experienced issues with woocommerce functions available in wp cron jobs, so these should be enough to get you going.

Comment: How can I add the 'product_cat' itself ?

Comment: @kroky How to get term_id based on a product category slug? (since id's can change but slug is usually the same)

Comment: @Amjad you could use `get_term_by('slug', 'the-category-slug', 'product_cat')` - check the docs, which are pretty helpful: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by

Answer (score 19):

You can load a product:

```
$product = wc_get_product($id);
```

Then set categories:

```
$product->set_category_ids([ 300, 400 ] );
```

Finally you're supposed to save, because operations dealing with properties use prop setter methods, which store changes in an array for saving to the DB later:

```
$product->save();
```

See the API Documentation for more information: https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html

It is better to use WC-provided functions for backwards and forwards compatibility.