# How to set category to product woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

is it possible to add a category to a woocommerce post?

I am creating my products as follows:

```
// creates woocommerce product 
$product = array(
    'post_title'    => $name,
    'post_content'  => '',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'post_author'   => $current_user->ID,
    'post_type'     =>'product'
);

// Insert the post into the database
$product_ID = wp_insert_post($product);
```

I have a category called "Tree" where I have to add the above product to.
I have tried the following but without succes. Is there some special way
to add a category?

```
wp_set_object_terms($productID, array('Tree'), 'product_cat');
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

After some trial and error I solved it the following way:

```
// Creates woocommerce product 
$product = array(
    'post_title'    => $name,
    'post_content'  => '',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'post_author'   => $current_user->ID,
    'post_type'     =>'product'
);

// Insert the post into the database
$product_ID = wp_insert_post($product);

// Gets term object from Tree in the database. 
$term = get_term_by('name', 'Tree', 'product_cat');

wp_set_object_terms($product_ID, $term->term_id, 'product_cat');
```

reference for more information:

- [How to programatically set the category for a new Woocommerce Product Creation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26690047/how-to-programatically-set-the-category-for-a--)
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by
- https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16394/how-to-get-a-taxonomy-term-name-by-the-slug

Comment: If you get $termID in different mode, and it's a string, WP creates a new term with name of the number, so add `(int)` before second arg: `wp_set_object_terms($product_ID, (int)$term_id, 'product_cat');`

Answer (score 5):

If you need multiple categories, just pass an array:

```
$categories = [ 'Some Category', 'Some other Category' ];

// Overwrite any existing term
wp_set_object_terms( $product_id, $categories, 'product_cat' );


// Or, set last argument to true to append to existing terms
wp_set_object_terms( $product_id, $categories, 'product_cat', true );
```

Comment: Note that this will overwrite any currently assigned categories.

Comment: You can pass true as the 4th argument to append your categories to the existing. wp_set_object_terms( $product_id, $categories, 'product_cat', true );

Comment: Thanks Zade and Matthew Ediger. I've updated the answer with these notes.