# Woocommerce / WP All Import: automatically add product to category if product name contains the category name

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce, wpallimport

I want to automatically add products to a category if their name contains the category (for example the product name is: Awesome brand baseball bat, the product should automatically be added to the category baseball bat). Is there a plugin that can automatically do this or even better: is it possible to add a rule to WP All Import to do this?

Setting the category like

```
$product->set_category_ids([ 300, 400 ] );
```

shouldn't be the problem, but how can I compare the articles names with all my categories so I can automatically add the products to them?

Comment: This question needs some refinement.  Where is a code sample showing your current process?  Where is the evidence that you've done a [google search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26690047/how-to-programatically-set-the-category-for-a-new-woocommerce-product-creation) on this question?  This is not a free programming service; it's to help people who are stuck and have already tried various solutions without success.

Comment: I tried to search for this issue, but couldn't find anything. Your link is a first start, but I don't know how to search the product title for the category name to automatically add it to the category.

I added some more information to my post though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Load all product categories via [get_product_categories( $fields );](https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_api_productsget_product_categories/)
2. Use [get the product name](https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_productget_name/) to find the name of the product
3. Loop through the categories and [compare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366730/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-contains-a-specific-word) each of them to the product name.  Depending on your situation and what values are in product category title or product names, you may need to [use a regex](https://medium.com/factory-mind/regex-tutorial-a-simple-cheatsheet-by-examples-649dc1c3f285) for this

When done, your code should look something like this:

```
$product_category_list = $product->get_categories();
$product_name = $product->get_name();
$categories_to_put_product_in = array();

foreach($product_category_list as $current_category) {
    if (strpos($product_name, $current_category->term_id) !== false) {
        $categories_to_put_product_in[] = $current_category;
    }
}
$product->set_category_ids($categories_to_put_product_in);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try your solution rn!